# Prove that $\,(A\cup B) \cap (A \cup C) \subseteq A\cup (B \cap C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How do I prove this problem? This is from the distributive laws on sets.

**Proof.** Let $\,x\in (A\cup B) \cap (A\cup C).\,$ Hence, $\,x \in (A\cup B)\,$ and $\,x \in (A\cup C)\,.$

I know that my proof should start on this but I do not know how to show the succeeding lines.

Comment: Well, you want to show that $x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$. What does this mean? Is it true?

Comment: You want a Proof by Cases.  $x\in (A\cup B)$ *and* $x\in(A\cup C)$ entails that *either* $x\in A$ *or else* ....

Comment: Btw, there holds equality, not only one side inclusion. Methods to proof can be truth tables for both sides logical sentences, or distribution property of conjunction and disjunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$.
We want to show that $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$.

Using proof by contradiction:

Assume $x\notin A\cup (B\cap C)$.

$x\notin A\cup (B\cap C)$ can also be written as $\lnot (x\in A\cup (B\cap C))$, so it follows that $\lnot ((x\in A) \lor (x\in B\cap C))$, and using the Demorgan's theorem, we get $\ ((x\notin A) \land (x\notin B\cap C))$.

From this, it follows that $\ ((x\notin A) \land (x\notin B) \land (x\notin C))$, and from this, we get $(x\notin A\cup B)$ and $(x\notin A\cup C)$, which tells us that $x \notin (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$, which is a contradiction as $x \in (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$.

This means that the assumption of  $x\notin A\cup (B\cap C)$ is false, as we wanted to show, so we can conclude $\lnot(\lnot (x\in A\cup (B\cap C))$ = $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$, hence proving that $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$.

Therefore, $(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)\subseteq A\cup (B\cap C)$.